# regex variable substitution in "replacement" argument

Tags: regex, r

I have a string in R.  I want to find part of the string and append a variable number of zeroes.  For example, I have `1 2 3`.  Sometimes I want it to be `1 20 3`; sometimes I want it to be `1 2000 3`.  If I store the number of appended zeroes in a variable, how can I use it in the "replacement" part of a `sub` command?

I have in mind code like this:

```
s <- '1 2 3'
z <- '3'
sub('(\\s\\d)(\\s.*)', '\\10{z}\\2', s)
```

This code returns `1 20{z} 3`.  But I want `1 2000 3`.  How can I get this sort of result?

One way is

```
s  <- '1 2 3'
z  <- '3'   
zx <- paste(rep(0, z), collapse = '')
sub('(\\s\\d)(\\s.*)', paste0('\\1', zx, '\\2'), s)
```

but this is a little clunky.

Comment: R is a little clunky when it comes to string manipulation.  Your solution is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenate operator from [stringi](http://stringi.rexamine.com) package:

```
require(stringi)
"abc"%stri+%"123abc"
## [1] "abc123abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to create the replacement string `zx` is pretty good. However, you can improve your `sub` command. If you use lookbehind and lookahead instead of matching groups, you don't need to create a new replacement string. You can use `zx` directly.

```
sub("(?<=\\s\\d)(?=\\s)", zx, s, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "1 2000 3"
```